# Error: expected an expression in C with initializing 1d array

Tags: c

I need to initialize array of

```
array[921600] = {229407, 229407, 229407,...,226851};
```

elements, I allocated array for 921600 elements and initialized array in function:

```
setArray(array);
```

and function looks like this:

```
Void setArray(Uint8 *array){
    array[921600] = {229407, 229407, 229407,...,226851}; //shorten
}
```

and then I get error in compiler: **error: expected an expression.**
When I initialize elements one by one it works like this:

```
Void setArray(Uint8 *array)
{
    *(array + 0) = (3);
    *(array + 1) = (2);
    *(array + 2) = (2);
}
```

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. And there's no way to "shorten" array initialization like you want to do. `array[921600] = { ... }` simply attempts to assign to a single element out of bounds.

Comment: Initialization happens at the point of variable declaration, so none of your examples are initialization. Furthermore you shouldn't allocate a huge array like that on stack or you'll get stack overflow.

Comment: If you already have the values, why don't you do a proper initialization when defining the array, like `uint8_t array[] = { ... };`?

Comment: By the way, those values are *very* large for 8-bit unsigned integers...

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can initialize an array ***as you declare it*** [^1]

For example:

```
int digits[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6 }; // Initialize an array of 8 numbers
```

However, after an array is created, you cannot use the same syntax to *assign* it.
  **Initialization** and **Assignment** are two different operations with different rules.

The closest thing to a bulk assignment I know of is an ugly memcpy using a compound-literal.

```
memcpy(digits, (int[]){3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6}, sizeof(digits));
```

Example Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int digits[8];
    
    memcpy(digits, (int[]){3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6}, sizeof(digits));
    
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", digits[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

But that technique would be extremely difficult (and wasteful) to do on an array of 921600 elements.   For a very big array, the data should likely be loaded from a compiled resource or a text file or a similar external source.

[^1]: Except for VLAs. VLAs cannot be initialized this way.

Comment: Using `sizeof(digits)` in the `memcpy` call isn't good, since there's no guarantee that there are enough elements in the source array. And using the size of the source array is not good either is it's larger than the destination array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this:

```
array[921600] = {229407, 229407, 229407,...,226851} //shorten
```

doesn't assign the entire array - it's attempting to assign a brace-enclosed list to a *single* array element (which is a syntax error), *and* that element is one past the end of the array (if there are 921600 elements in the array, then they are indexed from 0 to 921599).

You cannot assign an entire array's contents using the `=` operator - if you want to set all elements to the same value you can use `memset`, otherwise you'll have to assign elements individually.

Your compiler should also be yakking on `Void` and `Uint8` - are you sure you don't mean `void` (C is case-sensitive) and `uint8_t`?  And if you mean for the elements to be 8 bits unsigned, then they won't be able to represent values like `229407` or `226851`.

Comment: I disagree with *"otherwise you'll have to assign elements individually."*.  I demonstrated how an array can be bulk-assigned via `memcpy` with a compound-literal.

Comment: @abelenky: compound literals are still new enough for me that I never think about them.  And in this particular case, I don't think it'd be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work:

```
array[921600] = {229407, 229407, 229407,...,226851};
```

Because you're actually attempting to assign (not initialize) a single value in `array`, and the `{...}` syntax is only valid for an initialization.

If you have some fixed set of values you're going to use to set your array, you can place them in another array and copy them in:

```
void setArray(uint8 *array)
{
    static const int src[921600] = {229407, 229407, 229407,...,226851};
    memcpy(array, src, sizeof src);
}
```

By making the source array `static`, you avoid having a large temporary array that could potentially blow up the stack.